# vandermonde decomposition of a Hankel matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, matrix-decomposition, svd, hankel-matrices

Suppose, I have a Hankel matrix **H** of rank-**K** and size **L x M**, I want to decompose **H** into vandermonde decomposition as:
\begin{equation}
H = SCT^T
\end{equation}
where S and T are vandermonde matrices of size L x K and C is a diagonal matrix of size **K x K**.  Is there any relationship between SVD  and VDMD (Vandermonde decomposition)? And How to do this VDMD for the above case in MATLAB or manually?

Comment: There is a relationship between SVD and the Vandermonde decomposition in that both yield [rank factorizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization) of a matrix of interest. However, I don't believe that there is a way to compute the VDMD using the SVD.

Comment: One algorithm for obtaining the VDMD is [given here](https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~boley/publications/papers/HK97.pdf)

Comment: Thank you Ben.  I was going through that.